# Postgres syntax (Sqlite3 syntax that doesnt work in postgres)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, sqlite

I'm having trouble with postgres syntax.

My **code** is as follows:

```
output = Course.select("DISTINCT courses.*").where(:semester => Semester.current_semester(input[:semester])).where(:pending => pending)
output = Section.need_to_filter(input) ? output.joins(:sections) : output.joins("LEFT JOIN sections")
output = output.where(:category => input[:category]) if input[:category]
output = output.where('title ILIKE ?', "%#{input[:search_field]}%") if !input[:search_field].blank?
```

And here's the **error** image
[image: Error image]

It has something to do with the join, because that's where it stops, but since I have sqlite3 in development I'm not sure how to test it efficiently.

Can anyone help?

Comment: For the future, please please copy-paste the *text* rather than the *screenshot* of text. The error is in using `LEFT JOIN` without `ON` or `USING`.

Answer (score 2):

You miss `ON` statement in `joins`

```
...
output = Section.need_to_filter(input) ? output.joins(:sections) : output.joins("LEFT JOIN sections ON sections.course_id = courses.id")
...
```